# when hit enter go to next element vuejs2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i have function on click vuejs2 
this is the function

```
@change='units(chosed_item.id,$event)'
```

and this is the code for this function to send the id and put result inside array

```
units:function(item_id,$event){
  var unit_id = event.target.value;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: path+'unit_search',
        data: {unit_id,item_id},
        success:(data) => {
            this.voucher_items.push({
                id:data['id'],
                item_desc_ar:data['item_desc_ar'],
                item_unit_name:data['item_unit_name'],
                item_smallest_unit_cost:data['item_smallest_unit_cost'],
                item_smallest_unit:data['item_smallest_unit'],
                item_smallest_unit_selling_price:data['item_smallest_unit_selling_price'],
                item_discount_value:data['item_discount_value'],
                item_tax_value:data['item_tax_value'],
            });
            this.chosed_items = [];
         }
    });       
},
```

and i loop the voucher_items in loop
like this

```
<tr v-for="voucher_item , key  in voucher_items">
    <td>
        <input name='items_quantity_coast[]' type='text' class='form-control' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='number' name='items_quantity_quantity[]' min='1' class='form-control' v-model='voucher_item.quantity' required />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='number' name='items_quantity_discount[]' min='1' class='form-control' v-model='voucher_item.item_discount_value_input' min='1' max=''/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

how can i make the input focus go to last input in voucher_items like when i click unit function do the code above and focus the input in

```
<input type='number' name='items_quantity_discount[]' min='1' class='form-control' v-model='voucher_item.item_discount_value_input' min='1' max=''/>
```

thanks

Comment: firstly i think you should do `@change='units($event,chosed_item.id)'`  `$event` as first parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) ..

1. In your component, add a `directives` option ..

   directives: {
   focus: {
   inserted(el) {
   el.focus()
   }
   }
   }
2. Use your new `v-focus`directive to focus on the desired element ..

This will focus on the last input on your last row. If you want finer control on which element to focus you can create a custom directive and use it on an upper level element (the table element for example), then use normal DOM traversing techniques(`firtElementChild`, `lastElementChild` et al.) to target specific elements. The process will be the same.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks. Admittedly it's a bit hacky as it won't allow focusing on anything but the last row but I hope it serves OP's purpose.